# Cannot replace directives inside table by tr

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically fillup / create table in `Angular JS`. I created a directive `ns-row` to represent row in my table. I used `ng-repeat` directive to loop through all data within my custom directive `ns-row` as follow:

```
<tbody>
 <ns-row ng-repeat="row in data" row="row"></ns-row>
</tbody>
```

I used `replace:true` in my custom directive `ns-row` to replace it by valid `html table row - tr`. I have used `one root element` in the directive's template as :

```
<tr><td> {{row.id}} </td> <td> {{row.name}} </td> </tr>
```

Instead of displaying the output `Angular` traces a long error message in console.

But, if I removed the `replace:true` from the `directive` the error no longer exists but got the unexpected output.

And here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mnEUSP05BEDVVrrebRkE?p=preview)

Comment: could you add the error message and the code of the directive

Comment: I have placed the code in `Plunker`. Please follow the link there.

Comment: @StephaneRolland I am unable to add the error message as `stackoverflow` is not allowing me to add the content that contains link to localhost.But I think you can re-produce the error code from that `Plunker`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an AngularJS issue ([#1459](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459)).
There is a PR to fix it but I don't think it will be merged ([#3647](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3647)).

There are 2 ways to fix it without forking AngularJS:

1. Do not use `replace: true`
2. Wrap your `tr` with a `div` (resulting in invalid HTML)

   ```
   <div>
     <tr><td> {{row.id}} </td><td> {{row.name}} </td></tr>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Angular fails to use a non-standard element instead of a `tr`. To resolve your problem, you can use an attribute directive and place a `tr` element in your `ng-repeat`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data" ns-row="row"></tr>
</tbody>
```

and in your directive :

```
return {
    restrict : "A",
    scope: {
        row : '=nsRow'
    },
    template : "<td>{{row.id}}</td><td>{{row.name}}</td>"
}
```

[Here is your updated Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/iYE7EtMZRrjnld6S2vzI?p=preview)
More info on this bug [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459).